# human weight scale (60-180kg) with gram resolution

Tags: measurement

Is it possible to create a scale with a dynamic range of 5-6 figures? (measure the weight of a person in a gram resolution)?
If not why?
If yet, how?

Comment: Are you prepared to pay for a 20-bit ADC?

Comment: Most probably but is it actually required or will 1dp (80.1Kg) do the job?

Comment: Related question - how much does a lung full of air weigh?

Comment: Load cells (strain gauge) tends to have repeatability error, weigh the same mass over time and results will vary. A balance beam would be better, but then you have to manage the reference weight standard. What about the dynamic forces as the test subject is standing on the platform? There will likely be more than 2g worth of noise.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: 42 USD? Look what money fanatic people spent on things they don't need... Just sell it for 1299 USD and you'll be fine

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am actually interested in the difference in grams before and after. Will this make things simpler? Is there an analog device which can reduce DC in such an accurate scale?

Comment: I remember in high school chem class, weighing a dry chemical dessicant in a precision mg scale, seeing the mg digits slowly increase as the dessicant absorbed moisture... Putting aside the problems of weighing a live test subject, this level of precision requires temperature compensation, as well as serious attention to any sensor non-linearity. This will be expensive.

Comment: The answer to the first part is yes. The human rider to the question throws in dynamics that are difficult to control at this level of accuracy (breathing, metabolism, sweat, environment, wind). If you can control  the latter without killing the subject (or studying dead people only)  then you can achieve your goal.

Comment: an HX711 is $10 on sparkfun and will give you 24 bit ADC. for calibration wouldn't you really just need a bunch of known weights to give help with the non-linearity?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a digital balance beam scale.

Comment: Will the person be dead? if not the action of him / her  moving around will change the apparent weight by far more than a gram.

Comment: @Roger Rowland : in an atmosphere, approximately nothing after you account for the increased displacement. If you hold your breath and squeeze your lungs you may see a few grams...

Comment: @BrianDrummond ... too late ... paramedics and lawsuit are on their way ... you'd better hold *your* breath now ...

Comment: Yes. You can use a 24 bit ADC (AD7190) from Analog Devices. Its highly suitable for applications involving load cell measurements.

Comment: What about making one of [these](http://hackaday.com/2011/01/21/magnetic-digital-scale/), but bigger? Unfortunately, the original page of project is no longer available, but that's an idea. I would forget about strain gauges because, like others said, it is not precise enough. Precision weight scales are magnetic.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, since you will not find any suitable scale that has a repeatability within so big measuring range. Scales are usualy made of steel with applied strain gauges, so the steel can't bend and return at the same position, it has a hysteresis. Top grade weighing scales have 6000 divisions in legal to trade application. So the resolution is 200kg/6000 = 0.033kg (of you buy 200kg C6 scale). This can be improoved using 24 bit ADC, but not for legal to trade applications, still there is no warranty that it will detect 1g change,  it seems impossible to me.

Comment: [Sartorius Master Precision Balance LA64001S.  Max 64 kg. Resolution 0.1g .](http://labfish.de/en/details/sartorius/la64001s/599.html)  I don't have insight into how they are pulling this off.